# Could we make the FAQ clearer?

Tags: discussion, faq-content

It has been mentioned to me by a user that the FAQ does not explicitly mention that this site is also for non-Muslims.

Perhaps we can add to the part of the FAQ that says:

"This site welcomes all sects and groups that identify themselves as Muslim."

add on to it something that welcomes non-muslims as well.

how can the FAQ be edited to welcome explicitly welcome non-Muslims to this site?

Comment: should be added in FAQ